# AWS EC2 with Mosquito installed doesn't works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mqtt

i've installed [mosquito server](https://mosquitto.org/download/) on my ec2 machine on aws.
So i've added on inbound the port 1883 in listening:

[image]

and on aws ec2 by desktop remote i see:
[image]

So, the problem is, when i call with [MQTT fx](https://mqttfx.jensd.de/) my ip:
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port 1883, not works.
Still in waiting and the end i read:

```
  2019-03-27 09:42:41,453  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2019-03-27 09:42:41,454 ERROR --- BrokerConnectService           : MqttException
2019-03-27 09:47:07,021  INFO --- BrokerConnectorController      : onAdHocConnect
2019-03-27 09:47:07,035  INFO --- BrokerConnectorController      : connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 1883
2019-03-27 09:47:07,036  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2019-03-27 09:47:07,038  INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel             : MqttClient with ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx assigned.
2019-03-27 09:48:07,067 ERROR --- MqttFX ClientModel             : Error when connecting
```

So where i'm wrong ?? Thanks

Comment: Which IP address are you trying to connect to? AWS machines tend to have 2, and internal one and a public IP address (did you configure a static IP?)

Comment: and the AWS firewall needs to allow port 1883 and/or 8883